# backup error - windows server 2003

Tags: incremental-backup

I have server loaded with windows 2003 it is scheduled for a system state backup using Ntbackup utility, for some time it worked fine as scheduled , since a couple of days the scheduled backup isn't running, so i have daily manual job of taking backup, even the system does not shows any error for failure.

Comment: Verify the user account that this is running under is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check the scheduled task return code in the Scheduled Tasks app. That will give you clues as to what is happening.
- Verify that the user account that the task is running under is still valid. (Totally stolen from ErikA)
- Check the NT Backup log file for interesting bits of information. It's located at C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\NTBackup\data

Comment: Thief. :) <padding>

Comment: Guess what my favorite class was when playing NetHack. =)